# Explanation: Time Span absolute value explanation

Tags: c#

This isn't a coding question, it is more so a general question about the TimeSpan object in C#. One of the methods of the TimeSpan is a `Duration().` Per `MSDN, this method provides another TimeSpan object that contains the timespan as an absolute value.` I'm confused as to what absolute value means in this case. When I print the absolute value, I get 736179.14:46:32.5485475. I'm trying to understand what the absolute value of a timespan means so I can translate this value into the appropriate double variable.

Comment: An absolute value *usually* means "distance from zero" regardless of positive or negative direction.  What happens when you invoke that property on a negative timespan?

Comment: Yes, the example in [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration.aspx) is pretty clear, I feel..

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration(v=vs.110).aspx) has examples that seem pretty clear to me - just like real numbers, it turns a "negative" time span (start time after end time) into a positive one.

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve here?

Comment: A DateTime, for example, is a single point in time. A TimeSpan is a length of time, but it can be negative. `DateTime.Now() - DateTime.Now().AddDays(1)` gives a result of "negative 1 days", and `"negative 1 days".Duration()` gives a result of "1 day".

Comment: If you want a single `double` value then [`TotalDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx) seems like what you want.

Comment: There was no problem to solve as noted in the actual question. It was a what was an absolute value and how it related to a time span duration value. With that being said, I am accepting the answer because it provided the clarification I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute value means the distance from zero without regard to the sign of the number. So -4 has an absolute value of 4.

Your number: 736179.14:46:32.5485475 is the absolute value of a `Duration`.

It is represented in the following format (which I presume is what is confusing to you):

> Days.Hours:Minutes:Seconds.Fractional Seconds

```
736179 days  
14 hours  
46 minutes  
32 seconds  
5485475 Fractions of a second
```

Comment: Confused myself a bit so I deleted that comment.. If it's exactly 3 decimal places then it is "milliseconds", .333 is "333 milliseconds", exactly 6 is microseconds, and etc... This one is exactly 7 decimal places which doesn't have a prefix.. so I would just call it fractional seconds. .333 is technically both "333 milliseconds" and ".333" fractional seconds, I guess..

Comment: @Quantic Right, when creating the `Duration` the 4th param is taken as milliseconds, but is displayed as fractions of a second.